# Can't understand the SIFT keypoint extraction (not description) algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I have read two references about the SIFT algorithm [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) and [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) and I am not truly understanding how just some key points are detected considering that the algorithm works on the difference of Gaussians calculated on several resolutions (they call them octaves). Here are the steps from the technique according to what I've understood from the paper.

1. Given the input image, blur them with Gaussian filters using different sigmas, resulting in Gaussian filtered images. In the paper, they used 5 Gaussian filters per octave (they tell that two adjacent Gaussian filtered images were filtered using sigma and k * sigma gaussian filter parameters), and they consider 4 octaves in the algorithm. So, there are a total of 20 gaussian filtered images (5 per octave), but we will act on 5 Gaussian filtered images from each octave individually.
2. For each octave, we calculate 4 Difference Of Gaussian images (DOG) from the 5 Gaussian filtered images by just subtracting adjacent Gaussian filtered images. So, now we have a total of 16 difference of Gaussian images, but we will consider 4 Difference of Gaussian images from each octave individually.
3. Find local extrema (maximum or minimum values) pixels by comparing a pixel in each DOG with 26 neighbor pixels. Among these, 8 pixels are in the same scale as the pixel (in a 3x3 window), 9 are in a 3x3 window in the scale above (Difference of Gaussian image from the same octave) and 9 others in a 3x3 window in the scale below.
4. Once finding these local extrema in different octaves, we must refine them, eliminating low-contrast points or weak edge points. They filter bad candidates using threshold in a Taylor expansion function and eigenvalue ratio threshold calculated in a Hessian matrix.
5. **(this part I don't understand perfectly)**: For each interest point that survived (in each octave, I believe), they consider a neighborhood around it and calculate gradient magnitudes and orientation of each pixel from that region. They build a gradient orientation histogram covering 360 degrees and select the highest peak and also peaks that are higher than 80% of the highest peak. They define that the orientation of the keypoint is defined in a parabola (fitting function?) to the 3 histogram values closest to each peak to interpolate the peak position (I really dont understand this part perfectly).

**What I am not understanding**

1- The tutorial and even the original paper are not clear on how to detect a single key point as we are dealing with multiple octaves (images resolutions). For example, suppose I have detected 1000 key points in the first octave, 500 in the second, 250 in the third and 125 in the fourth octave. The SIFT algorithm will return me the following data about the key points: 1-(x,y) coordinates 2- scale (what is that?) 3-orientation and 4- the feature vector (which I easily understood how it is built). There are also Python functions from Opencv that can draw these keypoints using the original image (thus, the first octave), but how if the keypoints are detected in different octaves and thus the algorithm considers DOG images with different resolutions?

2- I don't understand the part 5 of the algorithm very well. Is it useful for defining the orientation of the keypoint, right? can somebody explain that to me with other words and maybe I can understand?

3- To find Local extrema per octave (step 3), they don't explain how to do that in the first and last DOG images. As we are considering 4 DOG images, It is possible to do that only in the second and third DOG images.

4- There is another thing that the author wrote that completely messed the understanding of the approach from me:

> Figure 1: For each octave of scale space, the initial image is
>   repeatedly convolved with Gaussians to produce the set of scale space
>   images shown on the left. Adjacent Gaussian images are subtracted to
>   produce the difference-of-Gaussian images on the right. After each
>   octave, **the Gaussian image is down-sampled by a factor of 2, and the
>   process repeated.**

What? Does he downsample only one Gaussian image? how can the process be repeated by doing that? I mean, the difference of Gaussians is originally done by filtering the INPUT IMAGE differently. So, I believe the INPUT IMAGE, and not the Gaussian image must be resampled. Or the author forgot to write that THE GAUSSIAN IMAGES from a given octave are downsampled and the process is repeated for another octave?